# Give an example of a function whose behavior becomes more erratic toward some limit.

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples

Is there a (preferably simple) function that becomes more and more erratic as we take the variable to some limit?  So suppose the limit is zero.  Each time the function is evaluated with a smaller variable going closer to zero the result will appear to have less and less of a pattern than when evaluated away from that limit.  I guess another way to say it is a function that becomes more orderly away from that limit. My initial interest is that I want to use the function as an analogy in an essay, but now I am genuinely interested.  When I say preferably simple, I mean not a huge messy equation and also something whose behavior toward the limit does not have infinitesimal behavior such as $\sin(\cot(x))$ toward zero. Below is a messy example of the "erratic" behavior I'm looking for.

[image: "Erratic" behavior toward zero]

Comment: What do you mean by infinitesimal behavior? I would have suggested $\sin(1/x)$ as $x\to0$, but I think this is essentially your example.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant I don't want.  Perhaps what I'm looking for doesn't exist, but I thought no better place to ask than here.

Comment: Your question is not easy to understand.

Comment: Define "erratic".

Comment: How about $(sin(a+x^n))/x^k$ where $k, n > 0,  a>=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a function in the sense you mean, but it may suit your purposes. Consider the borders of (for example) the Mandelbrot Set.

$$z\rightarrow z^2 + C$$

The solution is quite predictable within the centre of the structure where $|z|<<1$ and in the outer reaches, where $|z|>>1$. However, it behaves unpredictably where $|z|\approx 1$.